# CSS3 Gradient Leaving pixels un-colored in border-radius

Tags: gradient, css

After tinkering a bit, I've ran into a small visual snag. For some reason, my css gradient isn't coloring correctly around border radius's as you can see by looking @ [My Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SReject/Kgmxx/)

If you comment out just the gradient part of the css, all pixels are colored as they should be. Anyone know a quick fix for this, or able to spot what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to simply add the base background color after each gradient statement:

```
background: background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #900000 0%,#880000 40%,#790000 60%,#710000 100%), #710000;
```